# jQuery plugins not working for Ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Hey guys I have an annoying problem, am using bootstrap 2.3 and some jQuery plugins for form styling and stuff.

When I load in ajax content, more specifically select elements ... the jQuery plugin doesn't capture them and doesn't style them as a result.

is there any way that I can apply those plugins to Ajax loaded content other than having to load those plugins again whenever I make an ajax request?

Comment: Nope. you'll have to initialize the plugins on the new elements after you add them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Kevin said you need to initialize the plugin on the new elements after you load them. An easy way to do this globally is register a handler to be called for all ajax requests.

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
     $('.myForm').thePlugin();
 }
```

Comment: Oh God this is just too much work when I have like 10 15 plugins, what do people do when developing one page apps like soundcloud or stuff like that? all of the elements are loaded with Ajax ... there must be a way, has to be

But thanks guys anyways for the answers

Comment: If you init all of your plugins in a function you can just call the same function on ajaxComplete. Not sure how other sites do it. Try looking at their code if it isn't minified.

Comment: don't forget to close the brackets :) `});`