# jQuery scrollbar plugin (mCustomScrollbar) not re-initializing on AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently trying to implement a dropdown containing months of the year, where the user clicking on a month will load the appropriate range of gallery images via .load().

The AJAX call itself works, but I'm unable to get my plugins to re-initialize on the callback, i.e. the scrollbar does not load.
What adds to my confusion is that the scrollbar will load on the callback ONLY IF I don't use the plugin previously in my main.js .

I'm using the [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) plugin.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Release Calendar Month Dropdown -->
    <div id="dropdown-release">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Month
                <ul>
                    <li id="nov14">November 2014</li>
                    <li>December 2014</li>
                    <li>January 2015</li>
                    <li>February 2015</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="gallery"> <!-- ---------- GALLERY BEGINS ------------ -->

        <div class="hidden" id="gallery-note">
            <p><strong>Note:</strong> Tap gallery items to open<br/>in new tab</p>
        </div>  

        <div class="gallery-img">
            <a href="http://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/product/16752/sneakersnstuff-reebok-inferno-15-stars" target="_blank">
                <img class="lazy" src="img/loader.gif" delayedsrc="http://pngsneakerstuff.cachefly.net/images/105882/premium_full.jpg" />
            </a>
            <p class="imgDescription">November 22nd</p>
            <span class="hidden">20141122</span>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery-img">
            <a href="http://sneakernews.com/2014/11/13/bait-x-brooks-chariot-centennial-release-date/" target="_blank">
                <img class="lazy" src="img/loader.gif" delayedsrc="http://cdn.sneakernews.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bait-brook-chariot-centennial-3.jpg" />
            </a>
            <p class="imgDescription">November 22nd</p>
            <span class="hidden">20141122</span>
        </div>
.........etc
```

And here my main.js:

```
// within $(document).ready...

var galleryScroll = $(window).load(function() {
    $(".gallery").mCustomScrollbar({
        axis: "x",
        advanced: { autoExpandHorizontalScroll: true }
    });
});

$('#nov14').click(function() {
    $(".mCSB_container").load("releases/november/nov.html",function(response,status,xhr){
        $(".gallery").mCustomScrollbar("update");
    });
});
```

I've also unsuccessfully tried to solve the issue through .ajaxComplete as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122042/jquery-plugins-not-working-for-ajax-loaded-content).
Been stuck on this last bit for ages, help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I should point out:

nov.html is simply another list of .gallery-img divs.

Comment: I had similar problem. Instead of loading on .gallery try loading on    $(".mCSB_container") and then call update.

Comment: NICE. Works beautifully with that fix, thank you Krishna! You should put this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the plugin site you linked:

> update
>
> `Usage $(selector).mCustomScrollbar("update");`

Which is probably what you want to call in your callback instead of setting the whole thing up again.

Comment: Changed it to "update", same issue though unfortunately: Standard scrollbar and the actual website suddenly lets you scroll to the right out of the frame into blank canvas.

Thanks for pointing this out to me though, reminder to always check documentation first.